# Is there any mistake in the remark of president Trump?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw the sentence made by president Trump on the internet.
The sentence is here.

***interesting how the US sells Taiwan billions of dollars of military equipment but I should not accept a congratulatory call.***

I don't understand the 'interesting how'. How do I translate this sentence?
Please, tell me.

Comment: You could read it as: **It is interesting that the US sells Taiwan billions of dollars of military equipment but I am criticised for accepting a congratulatory call.** (Your version was a tweet from the president, whose tweets are not much concerned with correct grammar.)

Comment: It is a very clumsily worded sentence, but _Interesting how_ is a colloquial way of saying _It is an interesting fact that_, or _I find it interesting that_.

Comment: "How" is being used in a very informal style, and is the equivalent here to the subordinator "that". We understand "it's interesting how/ that the US sells Taiwan ..."

Comment: Tweets, like newspaper headlines, road signs, diary entries, and so forth follow their own, often non-standard grammar and conventions. And without getting too political, I think it is safe to say this tweeter pays no more heed to conventions of grammar or diction than to those in any other aspect of his life.